# Can I perform a nullable struct equality test without boxing?

Tags: c#, boxing

I have a `struct Foo : IEquatable<Foo>`. I'm trying to write:

```
bool isEqual = a.Equals(b);
```

Where `a` and `b` are both of the type `Foo?`. This code works, but `b` is being boxed! Is there a way to avoid boxing?

Comment: What are the declaring types of a and b?

Comment: Could you overload `Equals` with a type-specific version?

Comment: That is what `IEquatable<Foo>` forces. You must declare a `bool Equals(Foo other)` but you have to call it with `a.Equals(b)` and the compiler will not box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the static [`Nullable.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/213d9ey9) method:

```
bool isEqual = Nullable.Equals(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked `Nullable<T>.Equals` but it too was performing boxing. I didn't realize there was a `Nullable.Equals<T>`.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Yup, it's using the non-generic `Nullable` *class*. All a bit confusing, I admit :)